# How to change color of specific words in a webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, textview, android-webview

I'm loading a custom page in a an android webview
It is of plain text type

However,I want to change the font color of certain keywords.
What I'm trying to achieve is similar to the text editors of programming environments where certain  keywords are displayed in different colors.

For example "printf" in red,"scanf" in green,brackets in dark blue etc.

I have more than 50 pages i database. So,it won't be feasible to manually put in html tags to change font color of each word.

What is the solution for this ? Javascript or some inbuilt functions ??
How to implement it ?I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some way of iterating through your wordset.

Then when you find a word that needs to change color just replace that word with

```
<span class="blue">yourword</span>
```

and define the color for the class blue in your css file.